# DateTime and duration add

Tags: dart

Consider the following code:

```dart
void main() {

  var duration = new Duration(days : 1);
  print ("duration " + duration.toString());

  var d1 = new DateTime(2014, 10, 26);
  print ("d1 " + d1.toString());

  d1 = d1.add(duration);
  print ("d1 + duration " + d1.toString());


  var d2 = new DateTime(2014, 10, 20);
  print ("d2 " + d2.toString());

  d2 = d2.add(duration);
  print ("d2 + duration " + d2.toString());

}
```

and the output:

```dart
duration 24:00:00.000000
d1 2014-10-26 00:00:00.000
d1 + duration 2014-10-26 23:00:00.000
d2 2014-10-20 00:00:00.000
d2 + duration 2014-10-21 00:00:00.000
```

Why does October 20 and 26 behave differently. I have checked the same code for every day of the year and every year has one day in which the date + 1 day equals the same date.
Every year the date seems to be in October between 25/10 and 30/10.

Is this a bug or have I missed something?

Regards
Peyman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the Oct 26. (and the other days between 25/10 and 30/10 is due to daylight saving period ending.
The difference of 1h (23:00:00.000) indicates this as the cause.

Comment: Of course you are right. I had missed the part of DateTime being in local time. 

it is the daylight saving. 
October 20th is working as I expected (= next day) 

var d1 = new DateTime.utc(2014, 10, 26);

Corrects my issue.

Answer (score 8):

As per  Günter Zöchbauer answer - it is due daylight saving time.

To properly add day you may use the following:

```
var d1 = new DateTime(2014, 10, 26);
var d1 = new DateTime(d1.year, d1.month, d1.day + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Александр Бабич answer - you don't have to care about the range of the days in the month when creating the DateTime in constructor. For example

`DateTime(2014, 9, 57)`

will correctly return 2014-10-27 and will not introduce any daylight saving shifts.
Negative numbers work as well, but are offset by 1, because 0 also works e.g.

`DateTime(2014, 9, 0)`
`DateTime(2014, 9, -1)`

will yield 2014-08-31 and 2014-08-30 respectively